# How can I hide my player name in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My sister and I are building a map for Minecraft PE and we need to be able to hide our name for some part of it. As crouching isn't available in PE, how can we hide our name from other players?

Answer (score 1):

If you change your name to a space character then it will be 'blank' per se, but this won't work in multiplayer. As of the current version, you cannot have a space in your name to join someone else's world or have anyone join yours.

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet possible in the current version of Minecraft PE. Hopefully, Mojang will add stealth mode to the game in the future.

One thing you can do is change your player name to `.`. You can still see it, but it's very small, making it not very noticeable unless you know where it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you build chests around you other players cant see your name.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the shy nametags addon

Answer (score -1):

You use potion of invisibility and put on armour